# Problems With Ubuntu 13.04 Booting from Live DVD

Tags: installation, 13.04

Okay, so I've partitioned my hard drive so I can install Ubuntu on it. Every time I put the disk in, it takes forever for it to get off of the Ubuntu load screen, and when it does, it just takes me to the terminal and says that there was an error in mounting the file systems. I don't know what to do, and I've been trying for the last few hours. This is getting me very annoyed. Can anyone help?

Also, I don't know if this helps, but when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during the loading, it comes up with a wall of text saying it is failing to start line 7 or something.

[EDIT]

Now I am trying to install Ubuntu with a Live USB, but now the desktop is all I see, with a spinning cursor.

Comment: Did you tried to repetitiously press the up and down arrows in your keyboard during boot?

Answer (score 0):

When using live DVDs there is always the chance that your copy is corrupted or something like that.

Although, before checking it, put your DVD in the drive and turn on the computer and repetitiously press the up and down arrows in your keyboard, it may lead you to the boot options of the Live DVD, try first the option: ***Explore Ubuntu without installing***.

If it doesn't work try the second option: ***Install Ubuntu***.

If it fails too you should try the 4th option: ***Check disc for defect***, it may point out that your disc has a defect, so you just need to burn it again if it is re-writable.

But, if it doesn't point out any defect, it may be the DVD itself, I used to burn several DVDs, and sometimes, depending on the PC, a certain DVD just won't work, so the solution will be buying another one, preferably of a different manufacturer, and burn it again.

Of course if you want to try burning the same DVD again it can happen to work, there are a few cases that I just re-burned the same DVD and it worked, other that I re-burned it in another drive and it worked. DVDs and CDs behave all kinda strangely and randomly sometimes.

Although, if you have a USB flash drive that you can use, do it through the USB, it is much better.